# Detect if network access is disabled for the running app on Android 9 (Pie)

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

As of Android 9 (Pie), you can go into the app settings and disable an individual application from using Mobile data, Wi-Fi, Background data, and Roaming data. To get to this screen, you go to Settings > Apps > Apps > [AppName] > Data usage.

[image]

I'm trying to find a way of programatically detecting whether each of these options are enabled/disabled. Any help would be appreciated!